# Android Ndk & FFMPEG - Not able to compile on ubuntu x86

Tags: android-ndk, ffmpeg

I am following this:
[roman10's android ndk r9d - ffmpeg tutorial](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9)
I am able to run build_android.sh script.. but its not creating that ‘android’ folder in my source/ffmpeg folder !!
what should I do? Plz help me.

Another Doubt: The thing ‘arm’ in that .sh file is supposed to be changed according to machine env???? If that is the case, can you guide us for x86???

my build_android.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=/home/NDK/android-ndk-r9d
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-arm
function build_one
{
sudo ./configure \
    --target-os=linux \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-static \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-symver \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --arch=arm \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make
make install
}
CPU=i686
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```

I am using Ndk r10, ffmpeg 2.5.4, ubuntu x86.

Thanks for ur time.

Palak.

Comment: $NDK/sources/ffmpeg-2.0.1/android,   if you can not locate that try running the build as ROOT. You probably dont have user W permissions in child folders of $NDK on your system.

Comment: I was running script as Root. I have given 755 permission with -R. The problem is solved just by putting my ffmpeg folder outside of ndk/sources dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my script for building for both `x86` and `arm`. Seems that I was using the same script as you are trying to use as a base. If you need only x86, then comment the first `build_one` at the bottom of the script.

It's tested with NDK r10 on Mac, but should be working on Ubuntu too.

```
#!/bin/bash

NDK_PLATFORM_LEVEL=9
NDK_COMPILER_VERSION=4.8
NDK_ABI=arm

# Android now has 64-bit and 32-bit versions of the NDK for GNU/Linux.  We
# assume that the build platform uses the appropriate version, otherwise the
# user building this will have to manually set NDK_PROCESSOR or NDK_TOOLCHAIN.
if [ $(uname -m) = "x86_64" ]; then
    NDK_PROCESSOR=x86_64
else
    NDK_PROCESSOR=x86
fi

NDK_UNAME=`uname -s | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`


NDK=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT

function build_one
{
    if [ $NDK_ABI = "x86" ]; then
        HOST=i686-linux-android
        NDK_TOOLCHAIN=$NDK_ABI-$NDK_COMPILER_VERSION
    else
        HOST=$NDK_ABI-linux-androideabi
        NDK_TOOLCHAIN=$HOST-$NDK_COMPILER_VERSION
    fi

    SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-$NDK_PLATFORM_LEVEL/arch-$NDK_ABI/
    TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/$NDK_TOOLCHAIN/prebuilt/$NDK_UNAME-$NDK_PROCESSOR
    echo sysroot=$SYSROOT
    echo prefix=$PREFIX

make distclean > /dev/null 2>&1

./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-debug \
    --disable-stripping \
    --disable-static \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-symver \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$HOST- \
    --target-os=linux \
    --arch=arm \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --enable-pic \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make -j16
make install
}

CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm" 
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG="--cpu=cortex-a8"
build_one

NDK_ABI=x86
CPU=i686
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/x86
ADDI_CFLAGS="-pipe -march=atom -msse3 -ffast-math -mfpmath=sse"
ADDI_LDFLAGS="-lm -lz -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack"
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG="--arch=x86 --cpu=i686"

build_one
```

I also did replace lines in `configure`, that start with `SLIBNAME`, with these. The tutorial also mentions that.

```
SLIBNAME='$(SLIBPREF)$(FULLNAME)$(SLIBSUF)'
SLIBNAME_WITH_VERSION='$(SLIBNAME)'
SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR='$(SLIBNAME)'
LIB_INSTALL_EXTRA_CMD='$$(RANLIB) "$(LIBDIR)/$(LIBNAME)"'
SLIB_INSTALL_NAME='$(SLIBNAME)'
SLIB_INSTALL_LINKS=
```

Comment: Hey Dmitry, Thnx for the help. but, I m not still able to get that android folder inside sources/ffmpeg.. In that roman10 tutorial for ndk r6, he wrote that we need to create './android/armv7-a/ ' folder manually for ndk r6. Have you ever created any folder or Temp folder manually?  Thnx.

Comment: I wasn't putting ffmpeg sources in NDK folder as the tutorial says. I think that would be just wrong. Just extract ffmpeg to any directory, copy the script that I posted to build_android.sh, and run it. The script should create `android` folder. I wasn't creating any additional folders

Comment: Can't put formatted text in the comment. I added that to my answer

Comment: You are the man!!! You mad it.. by putting ffmpeg outside of source dir, I am able to get that 'android' folder... Thank u so much.

Comment: Hey, I am not getting this file : 'libavcodec-55.so' in ffmpeg/android/lib dir ??? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Try first without changes in the `configure`. It should generate `.so` file with version number and then other `.so` with links to it. If that works, then just play with the lines that should be changed in `configure`. The main reason is that android doesn't support those links for versions of `.so`

Comment: ya, now I am getting libavcodec-55.so and all that, But not getting libffmpeg.so file anywhere??? :(

Comment: It seems that you didn't changed the `configure` file. I just downloaded ffmpeg source code from https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg. Current commit is `f015d3d53916c09fff98bb350854e97fd6d9e227`. Then I copied the lines from my answer that start with `SLIBNAME` and pasted them into `configure` at 2779. Then copied the build script to `build_android.sh`, run `chmod +x build_android.sh` and then run the script itself, and then I get `.so` files in android folder without version numbers. Double check if you are not missing anything. And you can also check `configure` yourself where it creates `.so`

Comment: ah, and there should not be a single `libffmpeg.so`. It compiles a bunch of `.so` files and you need to link all of them to your app. In the build script you can disable features of ffmpeg that you don't need. There is a way of merging into a single shared object, but it will require a few more commands to run. However, I don't see any problems with using separate libs